# Has the beta api stopped delivering columnset or is it just me

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-addins

Yesterday I received data on the rest api using expand=columnset when I was resting against sharepoint listitems... today I'm not. I know its beta, but  can't seem to get my listitem data expanded. Anyone experiencing the same?

I can't find anything regarding this out there.

Here is the url I use:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sharepoint/sites/{siteid}/lists/{listid}/Items?expand=columnSet

result:[image]

Do you now where I can find info on builds for the beta api?

Best regards Ole

Comment: It seems to be working for me. Could you post what the result looked like?

Comment: Thanx @MarcLaFleur-MSFT for commenting, using the _italic_?expand=columnSet the result came back without the columnset (for both of my tenants) I've updated the post with the result

Comment: When adding the simple https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sharepoint/sites/{site=id}/lists/{list-id}?expand=columnSet(select=Title) it fails With  "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "The request is malformed or incorrect.",

Comment: This is also happening for me...

Comment: If @MarcLaFleur-MSFT has it working, but me (tested 4 tenants) and Julie not. hmmm, geographic placement of our tenants? Where to go for help?

Comment: @Sky Liu - Microsoft ?

Comment: I have the same issue. Even if you make a request for an individual list item, expand=columnSet only returns the item's metadata.

Comment: There is an open issue on the [GitHub Graph Documentation](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/1137).

Comment: I think its kinda incredible that there is a post regarding this on github, techcommunity and stackoverflow and nobody from the graph team has picked it up? nice upgrade of the Graph Exporer, but still nothing on the sharepoint beta api and expanded columnsets???

Answer (score 0):

got this from github post: solution is coming this or next week. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/1137#issuecomment-299263019